# Take profit for a certain percent of the position, leave the rest to stop loss

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

In tradingview I use a study and its related strategy version to backtest indicators. At the moment, I'm using very basic code in the strategy to exit the trades (based on a stop loss price derivated from swinglow/high calculated earlier in the script), the end of the script where the strategy order exit logic lives looks like this:

```
...

// Determine stop loss price based on swinglow/high
longStopPrice  = periodHighestSwingLow
shortStopPrice = periodLowestSwingHigh

// Submit entry orders
if (enterLong)
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true)

if (enterShort)
    strategy.entry(id="ES", long=false)

// Submit exit orders based on calculated stop loss price
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XL STP", stop=longStopPrice)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XS STP", stop=shortStopPrice)
```

As I'm using alertatron to interract with exchanges, the fact that you can use take profit for a certain percent of your position (for the record, through some function they call [trailling take profit](https://alertatron.com/docs/automated-trading/trailing-take-profit-order)) caught my attention. I'm now looking forward to implement the corresponding code in trading view to backtest the following scenario:

- if price raises of 1%, sell 1/3 of your position
- leave the rest of your position (2/3) and let it exit with current stop/loss logic (the one based on swinglows/high)

So far, what I tried was to implement logic inspired from [this tradingview article](https://kodify.net/tradingview/orders/percentage-profit/) and [this one](https://kodify.net/tradingview/orders/percentage-trail/) without success (as none of them actually use multiple exits orders based logic to exit their positions).

I also looked into docs `strategy.order` but it doesn't seem to be available examples in the docs. here is what I ended up with trying to place an additional order on entry but it doesn't provide data in the strategy tester output:

```
if (enterLong)
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true)
    strategy.order(id="stopLossLong", long=true, qty=(strategy.position_size/3), stop=(close + (close*0.01)))
    
if (enterShort)
    strategy.entry(id="ES", long=false)
    strategy.order(id="stopLossShort", long=false, qty=(strategy.position_size/3), stop=(close - (close*0.01)))
```

My current atempt is to use different `strategy.exit` calls with the same ID, nevertheless, the take profit based on % never seems to be triggered with the following code.

```
// Submit entry orders
if (enterLong)
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true)

if (enterShort)
    strategy.entry(id="ES", long=false)

// STEP 3: Submit exit orders based on calculated stop loss price
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    // if current closing price is upper position entry price plus 1%
    target_take_profit_long = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + 0.01)
    if close >= target_take_profit_long
        strategy.exit('XS STP', 'Short', limit=target_take_profit_long, qty_percent=25, comment='Close-Sell-Profit')
    // else, wait for current stop loss
    strategy.exit(id="XL STP", stop=longStopPrice)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    // if current price (close) is below position entry price minus 1%
    target_take_profit_short = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - 0.01)
    if close <= target_take_profit_short
        strategy.exit('XS STP', 'Long', limit=target_take_profit_short, qty_percent=25, comment='Close-Buy-Profit')
    // else, wait for current stop loss
    strategy.exit(id="XS STP", stop=shortStopPrice)
```

So here is the question: is it any way to implement multiple exits in a TradingView strategy so I can do both, securize à part of my position when some %of initial price is reached, and leave the rest to stop loss rule (in the context of a strategy).

Any input truly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I could achieve the desired result through the following code:

```
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    // if current closing price is upper position entry price plus 1%
    target_take_profit_long_1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + 0.01)
    if close >= target_take_profit_long_1
        strategy.exit(id='PROFIT LONG 1', from_entry="EL", limit=target_take_profit_long_1, qty_percent=25, comment="long: +1% / 25% of pos / 1% total TP")
stop=longStopPrice, comment="swinglow long exit")
    strategy.exit(id="STOP LONG", from_entry="EL", stop=longStopPrice, comment="swinglow long exit")

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    target_take_profit_short_1 = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - 0.01)
    if close <= target_take_profit_short_1
        strategy.exit(id='PROFIT SHORT 1', from_entry="ES", limit=target_take_profit_short_1, qty_percent=25, comment="short: +1% / 25% of pos / 1% total TP")
    strategy.exit(id="STOP SHORT", from_entry="ES", stop=shortStopPrice, comment="swinghigh short exit")
```

The idea is to use different `strategy.exit` calls based on conditions, specifying a `stop` parameter alongside a `qty_percent` one.

The result seems to work in backtest, adding trades events as desired between entry and exit, taking desired percents.